# How to say "today we will work wherever we want to, with our tasks" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario

How to say the following question in Spanish?

> Today we will work wherever we want to, with our tasks

I think it can be something like this:

> Trabajamos donde queramos con nuestras tareas

Is this a correct way to phrase what I want to say?

Comment: Apart from missing "hoy" for "today", the rest seems fine. However, in the original English sentence this "wherever we want to" is a bit ambiguous. Does it want to say "we will work anywhere we want"?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to conjugate the verb (*we will work*) in the future tense:

> Hoy **trabajaremos** donde queramos con nuestras tareas.
>
> Hoy **vamos a trabajar** donde queramos con nuestras tareas.

2. Being strict should replace **con** with **en**:

> Trabajaremos donde queramos **en** nuestras tareas.

The "[en](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EuPaWdO&o=h)" preposition indicates occupation. "[Con](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A5cH5M4&o=h)" not have that function, although any Spanish speaker would understand.